# SWT no more handles, but there should be

Tags: java, swt

in a Eclipse RCP application i get the exception:

```
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4423)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4312)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4283)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:472)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.createToolTipHandle(Shell.java:660)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.toolTipHandle(Shell.java:1944)
...
```

I added the Sleak tool to track if there is a leak on resources.
There is not. Sleak tells there are

```
63 Colors, 5 Cursors, 4 Fonts, 75 Images.
```

With the process explorer (MS sysiternals) i see this:

```
Handles 215
GDI Handles 48
USER Handles 23
```

From this information I think it is **not** a missing dispose problem.

Does anyone have an idea where I can proceed to analyze the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: If possible, please share with us the cause of the problem, and maybe the solution. I am quite curious what was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately not all "No more handles" errors are actually caused by over consumption of handles. For example, see this [SWT bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=386064) I reported a while ago.

In your case, CreateWindowEx returns NULL. Since I cannot reproduce the problem, I don't know if the code below will work, but I expect it to work. In case it doesn't, convert it into C and call it in a native method. I don't know if last error is reset or not by any other internal code in SWT. When you have the result of `GetLastError()` you go to the next step to fix the problem.

```
    int toolTipHandle = OS.CreateWindowEx (0, new TCHAR(0, OS.TOOLTIPS_CLASS, true), null,
                    OS.TTS_ALWAYSTIP | OS.TTS_NOPREFIX, OS.CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, OS.CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, shell.handle, 0,
                    OS.GetModuleHandle(null), null);
    if (toolTipHandle == 0) {
        System.out.println(OS.GetLastError());
    }
```

Since this is a tooltip creation, I suggest to set tooltip to `null` for your control and call this code on `SWT.MouseHover` event.

---

Edit: the idea is to call `GetLastError()` function, as noted in the `CreateWindowEx` [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632680%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

An easier way is to use the debugger: put a (conditional) breakpoint to stop when `CreateWindowEx` returns 0 at Shell:660 and inspect the `OS.GetLastError()` value.

Comment: I mean, when the application is in that state, not only tooltip does no more work, no new dialog can be opened as well. So can then set a break point in Control.createHandle line 704, check the handle is 0, then add "org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.GetLastError()" in the Expression view and see the 0 as result.

Comment: @keinfarbton all you have is the MSDN specification of `CreateWindowEx` linked above. According to comments there, it does happen for the function to return NULL and still set last error to 0. They also list there typical error causes. I'm sorry my answer did not help.